# Posible error en la sintaxis del código

Tags: javascript-objeto

Realmente el código corre en Android en si pero, me preocupa la sintaxis porque en Ipad se ralentiza
existe algún detalle en la sintaxis del código..

//Con este código logro que al ser pulsado uno de varios botones (opciones) 1.-quede inhabilitado 2.-darle opacidad  3.- y cambiar titulo y video en el escenario ademas de al momento de pulsar cualquier otra opción el botón anterior vuelva a estar habilitado y recupere su brillantes y repetir el ciclo.

```
var a=""
function carga01(e) {
if (a!=e) {
    if (a!="") a.style.opacity=1;
   a=e;
e.style.opacity=0.4;     
document.getElementById("subTVideo").innerHTML = 'POOMSAE KORYO';
document.getElementById("mp4_src").src = "../videos/koryo.mp4";
document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
```

//Este otro detecta que la reproducción a concluido y devuelve el foco y brillantes a el botón donde fue hecha la petición.

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("ended", function(){
a.style.opacity=1;
a="";
document.getElementById("subTVideo").innerHTML = 'VIDEO CONCLUIDO...';
document.getElementById("mp4_src").src = "../jpg/fuente.jpg";
document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
});
}
}
```

El código corre `http://enviasiete.com/tae2020/html/videos.html`

Comment: A nivel de optimización se recomienda no usar frecuentemente `document.loQueSea` repetidas veces, como ocurre en tu código. Es mejor crear una referencia a cada elemento una sola vez y luego usar esa referencia. Igualmente las modificaciones de elementos hay que agruparlas para luego modificar el elemento una sola vez, no varias veces. De todos modos es un código un poco cabeza loca, no entiendo por qué hace tantas cosas que parecen repetidas o por qué el listener depende de un `if`

Comment: Que me recomiendas para optimizarlos?

Comment: Explica lo que hace el código, pues es un poco loco y no logro entenderlo del todo.